# Union Operators to Dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I convert

```
x = 'a=b&c=d'
```

to

```
{'a':'b', 'c':'d'}
```

without explicitly looking and replacing `&` and `=` to `,` and `:` respectively?

Comment: Why do you not want to explicitly replace these characters e.g. using `split()`?

Comment: How do you know the way it needs to be converted to a dictionary unless you look for `&`, and `=` explicitly?

Comment: you need to write your own custom logic to achieve the use case, there is no special operator provided, if you have tried some work around, then update the snippet in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a DSL (domain specific language) for defining a `dict`. You have to parse the string, then evaluate the result. Luckily, that's as simple as

```
d = dict(kv.split("=", 1) for kv in x.split("&"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be misinterpreting the meaning of "explicitly looking and replacing". I would argue you can't do it without doing so.

But I also see no reason to avoid that.

```py
x = 'a=b&c=d'
mydict = dict(map(lambda y: y.split('='), x.split('&')))
```

What this does is best understood reading from the inside out.

1. It takes the string `'a=b&c=d'` and turns it into a list of substrings that used to have an ampersand in between them.
2. It takes one such `'a=b'` string and splits again, this time on the equal sign.
3. This operation is performed on the whole list, so we end up with a list of lists.
   `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]`
4. `dict()` turns that into a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x
'a=b&c=d'
>>> mydict[x[0]]=x[2]
>>> mydict[x[4]]=x[6]
>>> mydict
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
>>> #note that '&' and '=' are not "looked for" nor replaced
```